# PHP Insert into database script no longer works

Tags: php, sql

I've used this script for many projects and it has always worked flawlessly, but it decided to no longer work today on all my projects. I haven't changed a thing. Some help would be nice.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','sutdenlol1');

if(!$con)
{
    echo 'Not Connected to Server';
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'mineblox'))
{
    echo 'Not Selecting Database';
}

$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Username = $_POST['username'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];

$paassword = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (Email,Username,Password,) VALUES ('$Email','$Username','$paassword')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo 'Not Inserted';
}
else
{
    header ('Location: profile.php');

}

?>
```

Edit: Should be noted I haven't work on anything for a week, which before I left I checked, and it worked. I came back today, and it no longer worked.

Edit 2: It returns "Not Inserted"

Comment: And what is the problem ? Syntax error ? page show 'Not inserted' ? Are you redirected to profile.php ? You just say "it doesn't work", we don't kno what part

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Yeah it says "Not Inserted"

Comment: Strange thing how your query managed to work with extra `,` after `Password`

Comment: replace `if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))` by `mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error())` and tell us what it say

Comment: You also declare $Password and use $paassword in sql syntax... you sure it worked one day ?

Comment: @PierreGranger paassword is a hashed password

Comment: Right sorry missed that line ;) but the extra , should make it fail. Can you tell us what mysqli_error() render ?

Comment: It was the comma. It worked after I removed it. I'm not sure why it worked before, but I know it did. It works now again, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Email,Username,Password,)
```

You have an extra , in your your query